# calling instances in a class in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-class

Im sitting in a reseach project trying to build a class for one of our AGV:s (Autonomous Guided Viechle).
I will not show the whole class but i need some pointers so i can write programs for my students that are easy to use.

So my code looks like this(headers are created ):

```
import requests
import json
import ipaddress
import cmd

MiRTemplate = "http:///api/v2.0.0/"
headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic

def insertChar(mystring, position, chartoinsert ):
    #check for correct ip input from user
    longi = len(mystring)
    mystring   =  mystring[:position] + chartoinsert + mystring[position:] 
    return mystring 

 class mir(object):
    



    def __init__(self, headers,ip):
        self.headers = headers
        self.ip = ip
        
        print("MiR instance created!")    

    
    def getHw(self):
        host_hw = ip+"/hw/export"
        get_hw = requests.get(host_hw, headers = self.headers)
        print("it worked")
        print(get_hw.headers)
        return
```

In my first tries using the class i just called it like:

```
mir.getHw()
```

and got the printed response i requested

then i added user input, in this case an ip in order to GET or POST to a certain AGV(we have 2):

```
#user input
while True:
    try:
        user_ip = input("Enter ip adress of MiR: ")
        ip = ipaddress.ip_address(user_ip)
        print(f'{ip} is correct. Version: IPv{ip.version}')
        #convert back to string and insert into adress line for agv
        ip=str(ip)
        ip=insertChar(MiRTemplate,7,ip) 
        mir = mir(headers,ip)
        mir.getHw
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('ip Adress is invalid')
        continue
```

this worked as well
Now to my problem, i tried to add the following code:

```
while True:

    # Create an instance of the MiR class, pass the headers an ip
    
    try:
        
        userinput=input("""Which function do you want to use? \n\n
        1) HardWare Info. \n\n 
 
        type q to quit \n\n
        Please enter the corresponding number and hit enter >>>>> """)
        
        
        if userinput == 1:
            mir = mir(headers,ip)          
            mir.getHw()     
                    
                
        elif userinput== "q":
            break
        
            
    except ValueError:
        print("incorrect input")
        continue
```

But here i get no printout from the function, how do i resolve this?
I have 8 more function like the getHw that i want to add later on.

//David

Answer (score 1):

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function always returns a `str` object in Python 3, and will therefore never produce the `1` value you are expecting. You must try to convert the `userinput` variable to `int` or, simpler here, simply compare it to a plain string, like so:

```python
if userinput == '1':
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks soo much, such a stupid error on my part!